# Running "rails g devise User" 2 times by mistake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sqlite

While building a new application, I ran `rails g devise User` twice by mistake and now I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError, Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

When I `rake db:migrate`, I get a duplicate columns error from SQLite. How do I handle this?

Comment: Can you just delete the second migration file in db/migrate?

Comment: Deleting the second migration solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your db and run the migration again.

```
bundle exec rake db:reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the second migration file created from db/migrate and remove " devise_for :users" from routes.rb.